# Calculate Size of PE header in C / Capstone

Tags: c, windows

I'm struggling to write a C function to calculate the size of the PE header in a executable. I'm trying to disassemble a bunch of files using Capstone. In order for Capstone to disassemble the file, the data buffer has to start AFTER the PE header in a executable. Basically, I can't just give Capstone a file and say disassemble.

I know how to use Capstone and I have some functions written to start the disassembly process. But I don't know how to seek in a file to the end of the PE header. If someone could provide me with some pointers or tips I would appreciate it. Thank You.

-Mike

Comment: Are you passing a pointer to the `.text` section (where the code starts) within a PE mapped into memory, or are you passing a file offset?

Comment: the PE standard is how all Portable Executable files are to be laid out.  this PDF file: <http://www.openwatcom.org/ftp/devel/docs/pecoff.pdf> describes the variations, offsets into each header within the file, etc etc.

Comment: I'm trying to read into a buffer everything in a binary file except the PE header. I then want to past the buffer of data to Capstone for disassembly. Capstone thinks the PE is "illegal code" and will stop processing once it runs into it. That's why I need to strip out the PE header. Thanks. And thanks for the PE standard PDF.

Comment: @Mike  you say 'Here;s what I'm doing', but I don't see any edit that shows what you are doing.